# Create NSMutable Array from User Inputs through UITextField in Xcode

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to create an array that will store a float calculated from user inputs from two UITextFields. From searching the web I think I should be using an NSMutableArray. Ideally, there will be no set size of the array, as users enter more values I want it to expand, is that possible?

These values need to be saved in the app, even after it has been closed. From what I gather there are two options, CoreData or storing in a .plist file. I want to do the easier of the two, as I am still a beginner with iOS development.

If anyone could help me out and point me in the right direction as to setting up this array and saving the data, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly recommend you go through an Objective-C tutorial as this is pretty basic stuff.  Look at this StackOverflow question for recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3341844/558933 .  I've also removed the Xcode tag as this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a lot to write here, so you better watch the tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6fEolemTts&list=UUy-pGo1UB-rXTO21OXTt2wg&index=1

It's really good, and you will understand everything you want.